# How to get router's ip aka gateway in Android's shell?

Tags: shell, terminal, busybox

In a normal linux environment we can do

```
gateway=`netstat -rn | grep ^0\.0\.0\.0 | awk '{print $2}'`
```

or

`gateway=$(netstat -rn | grep ^0\.0\.0\.0 | awk '{print $2}')`

but since Android's busybox/magisk doesn't support `netstat -rn`, what other commands can we use to get the gateway or router ip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as simple as `getprop net.dns1`

Comment: This is only true when your gateway / router is also the DNS server. On home networks this will work but this will fail on more complex networks with dedicated DNS servers.

Comment: @GiantTree how to get it on a more complex network system